# Retrieve checkbox checked values of webgrid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, webgrid

I have a simple WebGrid with a check box column in it. When the user checks a few rows and submits the form, I should retrieve the values of those rows and save those values in the database. How do I retrieve the row values one by one? I'm posting my WebGrid code below:

```
 @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
 htmlAttributes: new { id = "DataTable" },
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(header: "Select", style: "centered", format: @<text><input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" title="@item.Id" value="@item.Id"/></text>),
            grid.Column("FirstName"),
            grid.Column("LastName")))
```

When the user clicks the submit button, it fires the below action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the form posts to the Submit function, and below you can see how to access the checked values, i.e. you use the name of the checkbox as the parameter for the action:

```
public ActionResult Submit(string[] chk)
```